# Proof using the Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, pigeonhole-principle

The theorem I am trying to prove says:

Given $n+1$ natural numbers, say $a_1, a_2,...,a_{n+1}$, all less
than or equal to $2n$, then there exists a pair, say $a_i$ and $a_j$ with $i \neq j$ ,
such that $a_i\,|\,a_j$.

I tried induction, but its not feasible, so I came up with a pigeonhole proof. I am not sure if my proof is complete so I still require some help.

**Proof:**
Consider all pairs of numbers of the form $(k,2k)$ with $k$ between $1$ and $n$. If $n$ is $10$, consider the following pairs: $(1,2)\\(2,4)\\(3,6)\\(4,8)\\(5,10)$

Our list contains $n+1$ numbers. But if we choose two numbers from any of these $n$ pairs, one will divide the other. By the pigeonhole principle we must pick two numbers from one of these pairs. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I can't speak with authority on this particular problem.  However, my experience with similar problems, is that I (for one) could not conquer such problems via math induction.  Instead, my experience was that often, I was forced into the pigeonhole principle.  That is not to say that you will have the same experience with this problem or similar problems.  I am simply relating what my experience has been.

Comment: I would use the pigeonhole principle, but I am also not sure how to proceed with that proof, unfortunately.

Comment: If you cannot proceed, consider proving a stronger statement. What relation is stronger than $a_i|a_j$? Why is there a factor of 2 in front of $n$? (Of course this refers to the pigeonhole proof)

Comment: Take your best guess as to how such a demonstration would go.  Then edit your query to show a legitimate attempt to solve the problem with the pigeonhole principle (assuming that that is the right course).  It is irrelevant how far you get, as long as your query shows a legitimate effort.  This will allow mathSE reviewers to conclude that you have shown work, and that therefore, they are free to provide an answer.  Re mathSE standards, see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).